# convert .csv(ANSI) into .csv(UTF-8)

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8, ansi

I have a japanese environment in my PC. So I need a program to convert my .csv ANSI into .csv UTF-8. I tried using this code:

```
string st = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train1.csv");            
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train2.csv",st.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

The file train2.csv is successfully created, however, the text become unreadable due to conversion. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `st.ToString()` isn't needed

Comment: Are the Japanese character mapped to ascii 128-255 or are they unicode (two bytes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the input file encoding isn't detected correctly so you should define it

```
string st = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train1.csv", Encoding.Default); //ANSI
```

[Documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_)

> This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats UTF-8 and UTF-32 (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected.
>
> Use the ReadAllText(String, Encoding) method overload when reading
>   files that might contain imported text, because unrecognized
>   characters may not be read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) class can support reading files with encoding

```
StreamReader st = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\train1.csv", 
                                                 System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

After that you can write your data to the file based on [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_)

Comment: ASCII doesn't decode any characters that UTF-8 doesn't decode to the same character. So, the example of ASCII goes off in the entirely wrong direction.